# Is there a different markup for CSS3?

Tags: css

I just a have simple question.  I coded my HTML5 website and used some CSS3.

Is there a different markup for CSS2 and CSS3?

When I checked my HTML at the W3C, it validates 100%. But not my CSS, because it says that
some elements can't be used in CSS2 but can be used in CSS3.

The markup I use is @charset "utf-8"

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean?  Of course they're different... that's why it's called CSS **3**.  Explaining all the details about _how_ they're different would consume many pages.

Comment: Well, what I would like to know is wich markup I should use to validate my css2/css3 file.

Comment: If you want 100% valid CSS, then just use whatever markup is required as per the validation report.  Otherwise, I'm not understanding you.

Comment: Does your header info look like this?  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>

Comment: Yes it does. But I think I get the point now. I tought it could be kinda same like html5, strict, transitional you know, using different markup for css3. thanks

Comment: @MikeDukeHall that's HTML5 and HTML5 isn't CSS3. You can use HTML2.1 with CSS3...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I validate my CSS3 document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491972/how-can-i-validate-my-css3-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no special markup. Use normal CSS and a browser will parse this with the newest CSS3 parser.

CSS3 is in beta mode. The most browsers doesn't actually support the CSS3 functions, they are testing with it (so we need to use prefixes like -webkit-; -moz-; -o-; -ms-; -khtml-).
And W3C doesn't support these prefixes. You can set the W3C validator to CSS3 under *more options*, but you will also get errors because of the prefixes.

Comment: Oke yeah I checked it under 'more options' and your right. Did'nt knew this. My css3 errors are now good to go. Thanks for your explenation.

Comment: What exactly is "_normal_ CSS"?

Comment: @Sparky672 I think '*normal*' CSS is the newest CSS version. Because CSS doesn't has a doctype or something else, it's just CSS.  But you can also say the latest stable CSS version is '*normal*' CSS, and then CSS2.1 became the normal CSS.

Comment: Do you mean "Standards compliant CSS"?